# How to make a Python program that recognizes words common to 2 text files?

Tags: python, encryption

So, I'm making a python program that will read the code from a .txt (source.txt)file, and see if source.txt has any words that are there in a certain wordlist (words.txt). Also, I need it to tell me which is the common word.
SO, any idea how to do this?

Comment: How about to load the list of words and increase the counter for each word every time you face it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text File:-

```
 Hello, How are you today
 I am doing very fine fine
 I am also very cool
 My friends are cool too
 We are all very cool
```

Code: -
Not using any list comprehensions deliberately.

```
index = []      #Empty List
check = ['fine', 'cool']   #Words to check for
with open('Sample', 'r') as file:  #Open Text File
    for line in file:                 #Line in text file
        for word in line.split():      #Split the line into words
            for i in range(len(check)):   #Check if words from check match the words in the line
                if word == check[i]:          #i equals the index of the word in the list "check"
                    index.append(i)            #We add the index to our index list


#Find the most common index in our index list
max = 0
res = index[0]
for i in index:
    freq = index.count(i)
    if freq > max:
        max = freq
        res = i              #The element with this index in "check" is the most common
print("The most common word is :", check[res],"It occurs", max, "times in the file")
```

Output:

```
The most common word is : cool It occurs 3 times in the file
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Read from source txt file, either use regular expression or split to get list of words from the text file. Methods may vary.
2. Do same thing to your words.txt
3. Set & operator

below is bad but a working example :

```
f = open('./source.txt').read()
f2 = open('./words.txt').read()

a = set(' '.join(f.split('\n')).split(' '))
b = set(' '.join(f2.split('\n')).split(' ')) 


print (a&b)
```